# Problema con expresion regular

Tags: php, jquery, regex, validación

Tengo un problema con una expresion regular, quiero que solo acepte letras y espacios (y si es solo espacio que no lo envie)

Estoy usando esta: `/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ/s]{3,12}$/`

Pero si intento enviar el formulario con un espacio lo toma como verdadero e igual lo envia como si tuviera un text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta te debería servir:

```
/^\s*[a-zà-ÿ]+[\sa-zà-ÿ]*$/gi
```

La explicación sería: La cadena opcionalmente puede comenzar con 0-N espacios, después forzosamente debe continuar con 1-N letras, y opcionalmente puede terminar con 0-N letras o espacios. Es decir, solo puede contener letras o espacios pero es obligatorio que al menos tenga una letra.

Comment: muy util, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error en la expresión, porque `/s` no es un espacio, de hecho, deberías obtener un mensaje de error porque estás usando la diagonal `/` como delimitador. La representación para espacios es `\s`, pero también incluye otros caracteres como tabulador o salto de línea, por lo que lo adecuado es incluir un espacio  , sin caracteres de escape.

Podrías intentar con:

```
/^([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,})( ?)([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,}){3,12}$/
```

Lo que hace es buscar 3 grupos:

1. `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,}` Una o más letras
2. `?` Nada o un solo espacio
3. `[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,}` Una o más letras
4. `{3,12}` Todo el conjunto debe tener entre 3 y 12 caracteres

El único problema con esto es que solo te va a permitir un espacio.

```js
let regEx = /^([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,})( ?)([a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]{1,}){3,12}$/;

console.log(regEx.test('SO español'));
console.log(regEx.test('sinEspacio'));
console.log(regEx.test('dos  espacios'));
console.log(regEx.test(' afuera '));
```

Comment: hola @Triby me funciona bien con un solo espacio, pero si quiero colocar hola como estas .. no lo permite